# Which eclipse package to use with google app engine?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am going to develop on Google app engine platform in java and I don't know which eclipse download package I should get.

I don't know if the plugin supplied by Google has everything required and the classic package will sufice or if one could get some advantage downloading one of standard java packages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin provided by Google Eclipse at https://developers.google.com/eclipse/ has everything that you need to develop GAE applications.

I am not sure what you are referring to as the classic package but if it is Eclipse Classic that you are talking about then it will suffice.

Few other points:

- Make sure that you download the correct plugin version for the Eclipse version that you are using. Go to https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/download and use the version that matches your installed Eclipse version.
- When you begin the process of installing the plugin, you will see a screenshot like https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.2 where you will be given the option of what components to install. You can see that one of them is required but the rest are optional. I suggest that you go with selecting atleast the SDKs component.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

I developed some applications that uses google app engine and from my experience the eclipse plugin that google provides is sufficien but you need to install all the components of it.